# Can gazebo_ros actually use bullet?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, bullet, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen references to bullet and its use with gazebo, but haven't seen any specific information on whether its work in progress or its actually possible now.

Anyone know if its possible and how to do it, or where to find instructions for doing so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9798/can-gazebo_ros-actually-use-bullet?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the Gazebo roadmap, full Bullet support is a long-term goal.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Roadmap

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3